How the TabView internally works in SwiftUI
I want to build my own TabView in SwiftUI while avoiding the type eraser AnyView. To understand this better, I looked into how TabView is implemented in SwiftUI.
It seems that TabView uses a @ViewBuilder, as seen in its initializer:
public struct TabView<SelectionValue, Content>: View where SelectionValue: Hashable, Content: View {

extension TabView where SelectionValue == Int {

    nonisolated public init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content)
}

}
What I don’t understand is: If TabView uses a @ViewBuilder, how is it able to handle an unlimited number of views? As far as I know, @ViewBuilder has a limit of 10 views. Could you explain why this limitation doesn’t apply to TabView?

The 10-view limit has already been lifted since long ago.

Look into SwiftUI.Layout or the new ForEach that can separate views from "Content". Also look at the "Interfacing with UIKit" tutorial, Apple shows an example there that uses "pages". All of these things combined offer a glimpse of Apple's approaches.

Since I am using iOS 15 and the new ForEach functionality is unfortunately only available in iOS 18, I discovered _VariadicView. It has a function:
func body(children: _VariadicView.Children) -> some View
This allows me to iterate through the child views dynamically.
